# Mapeamento OneToMany com tabela associativa com HIBERNATE - JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, jpa, jpql

Preciso fazer um mapeamento com Hibernate de uma relação `1:N` em duas tabelas, porém existe uma tabela associativa que possui como colunas as ids das outras duas tabelas.

Exemplo:

A tabela `Servicos` pode possuir muitos `Itens` e cada item só pode fazer parte de um servico.

E existe uma tabela `servicos_itens` que contém a ID das outras duas tabelas.

Comment: Essas chaves estrangeiras na tabela associativa são também ids dessa tabela (ou seja, são chave composta) ou ela tem, além desses 2 campos, um campo específico próprio para id?

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seria algo assim:

```
@Entity
class Servico {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "servico")
    private List<ServicoItem> listaServicoItem;
}

@Entity
class Item {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "item")
    private ServicoItem servicoItem;
}

@Entity
class ServicoItem {

    @JoinColumn(name = "servico_id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Servico servico;

    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    @OneToOne
    private Item item;
}
```

E usando:

```
List<ServicoItem> listaServicoItem = servico.getListaServicoItem;
Item item = listaServicoItem .get(0).getItem();
item.getServicoItem().getServico();
```